# ROS2 Localization mode in slam_toolbox

Tags: ros2, slam, localization, nav2

I am currently comparing different localization methods for nav2 on my ROS2-humble workspace. Right now, I'm trying to integrate slam_toolbox's localization launch mode with nav2. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to load a previously saved map using `ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py use_sim_time:=True map:=path/to/my_map.yaml`, as the map immediately gets overridden by a fresh map published by the localization_slam_toolbox_node.

I've also tried setting `mode: localization` and `map_file_name:/path/to/file/filename` (I've tried entering both the .posegraph and .data, and .yaml filenames) in my mapper_params_localization.yaml file, but it does not seem to work as RVIZ still shows me a fresh map each time.

I feel like I've hit a brick wall and am unsure of how to proceed. I'd greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

SLAM Toolbox localization uses a serialized pose-graph from a SLAM Toolbox mapping session, you cannot use pre-rastered maps with it and should not be loading or serving a map yaml when using it.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I attempted to use the serialize map tool in SlamToolboxPlugin on RVIZ when using localization launch. On doing this, I got the error `[localization_slam_toolbox_node-1] [ERROR] [1711365801.527196557] [slam_toolbox]: LocalizationSlamToolbox: Cannot call serialize map in localization mode!`. 

Is the localization launch mode not designed to do this function? If so, could you please tell me the intended way to use the localization launch file?

Comment: continuing from my previous reply, I also tried generating the serialized posegraph using online async launch mode and tried deserializing it when running localization launch but I get this error, `[localization_slam_toolbox_node-1] [ERROR] [1711459328.431704839] [slam_toolbox]: Requested a non-localization deserialization in localization mode.
`

Comment: You have to serialize your map from your mapping session.